# How to validate a radio button in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a group of radio buttons that check for the user's gender.

this is my radio button mark up.

```
export default class Gender extends React.Component {
    genderRow(gender) {
        return (
            <Radio onBlur={this.props.validate} key={gender.id} name="gender" value={gender.id} label={gender.text} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        )
    }
    render() {
        let genderError;
        if(this.props.errors.gender) {
            genderError = <span className="has-error">Gender is required</span>
        } else {
            genderError = null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {genderError}
                {this.props.gender.map(g => this.genderRow(g))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

onBlur I am trying to call the following function.

```
validate(event) {
        let name = event.target.name;
        let errors = this.state.errors;
        if(!event.target.value) {
            errors[name] = true;
            this.setState({ errors: errors })
        }
    }
```

The issue is as follows. Since the radio button is a controlled component, there is always a truthy value, which means that when I check for `!event.target.value` it will return false, and this is happening even if the user didn't actually choose a value.

Comment: not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but can you not do !event.target.checked?

Comment: im gonna try that, tho I have a thought that it won't work. I wanna test it first tho.

Comment: OK It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onChange` handler, have it set the checked state:

```
onChange: function() {
  this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
}
```

And then adjust your validation to:

```
validate(event) {
  let name = event.target.name;
  let errors = this.state.errors;
  if(!event.target.checked) {
    errors[name] = true;
    this.setState({ errors: errors })
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I played around with your suggestion and the one from the comment. This is what is working for me. I don't need to change my onChange, it can still check for value as opposed to checked. This good because now I don't need to have more than 1 on change which means less code. I do however need to have a separate validator for my radio buttons to check for checked as opposed to value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually React is a VIEW. So you should know that it does not have rich built in validation stuff like Angular have. If you have a lot of validation in plans or already you should look to some more advanced tools for this. Example - use Backbone models together with react [react-backbone](https://github.com/jhudson8/react-backbone)(just as a live example)